# Finding clients and marketing myself

Tags: working-from-home, consulting, programmer

Im a fresh graduate from uni and im trying to enter the freelancing word, however im not sure how.. its such a big community with many experienced people. How can someone such as me face and get clients if 9+ years experienced people are there? How can i market myself and find clients? How can i market my skills? I already have a portfolio but no one knows about it. How can i make it visible what is the key to start getting projects and gaining real word projects experience? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a **fresh graduate** as you said then you probably should not have a good portfolio as there are already experienced freelancers out there in the market.

I suggest you to get some work done first, you can pick the work from your friends that are already working or you can low down your rates on freelancing sites, and  stay connected with the community of your choice that will help you to create a better portfolio. After that I think it will be easy to dive into freelancing world.

Comment: Great advice, but how can i find clients? On sites it's difficult because there is a lot of competition. Is there anyway to find clients even if i lower my rates?

Comment: As i said you have to be connected with the community, for example if you are a software developer you can connect with the community like **codeproject** or **stackoverflow**. And create your profile better among community there you can get better opportunities. or you can contact your known friends already working in the same area.